# How to open an URL in my default browser if it's HTTPS and in the WebView if it's HTTP

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a Java-based Android app.

I wanna open links inside my app's `WebView` as long as URLs are `HTTP` and open URLs that include `HTTPS` in my default browser.

I have tried this code but it always opens in WebView even though I open URLs that include `HTTPS`.

This is my code:

```java
//URLs
webv.loadUrl(Const.PATH_RESTAURANT + "res.pl?resUID=" + LoginActivity.mUserCD);

//condition to check url
if (Const.PATH_RESTAURANT.contains("https")) {
    //open in default web browser
    webv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
} else {
    //open in webview
    webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Comment: `this is my code` Where do you have that code? You are not checking the clicked url.

Comment: `Const.PATH_RESTAURANT` seems to imply a constant. Don't you want to check a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use Intent.ACTION_VIEW

```
//condition to check url
if (Const.PATH_RESTAURANT.contains("https")) {
    //open in default web browser
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.example.com")); 
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    //open in webview
    webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```